# Core data - binding related problem in NSNumberFormatter and NSDatePicker

Tags: cocoa, core-data, datepicker, cocoa-bindings, nsnumberformatter

I am trying a core-data sample application, from Cocoa Programming - Aaron Hillegass.

In it there is an entity Car, with following properties:

1. condition - Int 16
2. datePurchased - Date
3. makeModel - String
4. onSpecial - Boolean
5. photo - Binary
6. price - Decimal

There are certain view objects such as-

1. TableView
2. DatePicker
3. Image Well, etc.

Some of the bindings performed are-

1. TableView -> TableColumn with NSNumberFormatter (set as currency)->  value: arrangedObjects.price
2. DatePicker -> value: selection.datePurchased

Problems are:

1. In TableColumn with NSNumberFormatter it is not accepting any decimal numbers which I am entering for currency, such as - 123,00 or 123.45 or +235 or 567. It is always displaying this alert message: Formatting error.
2. Whenever I am selecting a row in table and changing its corresponding value in date picker, it is simultaneously changing the values for other records, ie. if for first row in table I have set it to 12/25/2004, it is keeping it 12/25/2004 for other rows.

Can anyone help me to resolve my problems? The source code can be found [here](http://db.tt/o9870RZ)

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 0):

The link to your code gives me a `404`.  The `NSNumberFormatter` is intended to be used with the `NSTextFieldCell` in your table, not the table column.  If you're doing this in Interface Builder, check in the list view to see that the objects are arranged in the hierarchy:

```
NSTableView -> NSTableColumn -> NSTextFieldCell -> NSNumberFormatter.
```

Comment: Hi Sean, thanx for your reply :)... the hierarchy is same as you asked to check ie. NSTableView->NSTableColumn->NSTextFieldCell->NSNumberFormatter. It is quite surprising that you are unable to download the project from above link, I have uploaded it in public folders in my drop box account, the actual link is- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9999259/CarLot.zip

Answer (score 0):

Checked the code again on my home network and your link worked fine.  The problem with the project is that you have to enter the currency symbol when you edit the value ($ for me).  To remove this requirement, check the 'Lenient' checkbox for the formatter in IB.

Comment: When I run it, it correctly changes the date to the value entered.  It seems that they are all using the same pointer until they're initialized, though, so changing one appears to change all.  But if you change them individually I found that the value is properly updated for the selected objects.  If you use a default value for the date property you should avoid this problem.  In your data model, choose a default date or you can use "Now" to get the current date.